# Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement using DoCmd.RunSQL method in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

My first error was the "missing semi-colon at the end of SQL statement" which has gone away, but now I have a recurring Syntax error. I am sure I have them in the same order, I made the field list and then copied it for the value list. I believe it is probably an error such as missing a space somewhere, but after a couple hours I still cannot find it.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL " INSERT INTO [Tbl_PartCreationLog] " & _
             " (Part_Number, Customer_Name, Ship_To_Location, Unit_of_Measure, Operation1, Operation2, Operation3, Operation4, Operation5, Operation6, Operation7, " & _
             " Operation8, Operation9, Operation10, Operation11, Operation12, Operation13, Operation14, Raw_Material, RIP_Width, BD_FTG_Factor, RIP_Scrap_Rate, Resaw_Passes, " & _
             " Yield_Cut , Grade, QTR, Substrate, Substrate_Thickness, Substrate_Width, Substrate_Length, Optimal_RIP_Size, Required_RIP_Size, Off_Fall, Cuts_Per_Sheet, " & _
             " Thickness, Width, Length, Size_Description, Moulder_Number, Number_Of_Passes, Mould_Scrap_Rate, Wrap_Number1, Wrap_Color1, Wrap_Slit1, Wrap_Number2, " & _
             " Wrap_Color2, Wrap_Slit2, Wrap_Number3, Wrap_Color3, Wrap_Slit3, Foil_Number1, Foil_Color1, Foil_Slit1, Foil1_Number_Slits, Foil_Number2, Foil_Color2, " & _
             " Foil_Slit2, Foil2_Number_Slits, Foil_Number3, Foil_Color3, Foil_Slit3, Foil3_Number_Slits, Foil_Number4, Foil_Color4, Foil_Slit4, Foil4_Number_Slits, " & _
             " Finish_Number, Step1, Step2, Step3, Step4, Step5, Step6, Step7, Step8, Step9, Step10, Drawing_Number, ECN_Number, Customer_Part_Number, Part_Type, Quote, " & _
             " Lumber_Notes, Moulder_Notes, [Wrap/Foil_Notes], Paint_Notes, Assembly_Notes, Package_Notes, Is_Active, Access_ID) " & _
             " " & _
             " SELECT Part_Number, Customer_Name, Ship_To_Location, Unit_of_Measure, Operation1, Operation2, Operation3, Operation4, Operation5, Operation6, Operation7, " & _
             " Operation8, Operation9, Operation10, Operation11, Operation12, Operation13, Operation14, Raw_Material, RIP_Width, BD_FTG_Factor, RIP_Scrap_Rate, Resaw_Passes, " & _
             " Yield_Cut , Grade, QTR, Substrate, Substrate_Thickness, Substrate_Width, Substrate_Length, Optimal_RIP_Size, Required_RIP_Size, Off_Fall, Cuts_Per_Sheet, " & _
             " Thickness, Width, Length, Size_Description, Moulder_Number, Number_Of_Passes, Mould_Scrap_Rate, Wrap_Number1, Wrap_Color1, Wrap_Slit1, Wrap_Number2, " & _
             " Wrap_Color2, Wrap_Slit2, Wrap_Number3, Wrap_Color3, Wrap_Slit3, Foil_Number1, Foil_Color1, Foil_Slit1, Foil1_Number_Slits, Foil_Number2, Foil_Color2, " & _
             " Foil_Slit2, Foil2_Number_Slits, Foil_Number3, Foil_Color3, Foil_Slit3, Foil3_Number_Slits, Foil_Number4, Foil_Color4, Foil_Slit4, Foil4_Number_Slits, " & _
             " Finish_Number, Step1, Step2, Step3, Step4, Step5, Step6, Step7, Step8, Step9, Step10, Drawing_Number, ECN_Number, Customer_Part_Number, Part_Type, Quote, " & _
             " Lumber_Notes, Moulder_Notes, [Wrap/Foil_Notes], Paint_Notes, Assembly_Notes, Package_Notes, Is_Active, Access_ID " & _
             " " & _
             " FROM Qry_PartCreation " & _
             " " & _
             " WHERE Access_ID = " & Me.Tbl_MasterPartsListAccess_ID & _
             " ; "
```

One thing I am not sure of is the ending - I have never referenced a form control while using VBA to execute an SQL string. Tbl_MasterPartsListAcccess_ID is an autonumber field, and for the life of me I cannot find the syntax for numeric fields anywhere. I have 1,000 examples of the date syntax but not numeric lol.

Comment: Since Access_ID must be a number field in order to receive autonumber key, don't use apostrophe delimiters. The parentheses around the SELECT fields may be an issue as well. Multiple fields with similar names indicates a non-normalized data structure.

Comment: Names with spaces or punctuation/special characters or are reserved words must be enclosed with brackets: `[Wrap/Foil_Notes]`. Advise not to use those in naming convention.

Comment: @June7 The fields are the same name because they hold the same information, and the options for the combo-box are gathered from the same table. While inside a query I have renamed them to TableName_Access_ID so as to not create multiple reference issues. I will be changing the naming convention as advised. 

I have taken out the apostrophes and parentheses and still no dice. I will update my post to reflect the code changes.

Edit: I forgot to add in the [] around Wrap/Foil_Notes, once that was added it finally no longer errored out. For some reason it is now only posting 10 of the fields.

Comment: Since I don't know your data, can't address that issue. Be aware there is supposed to be a limit of 24 line continuations in VBA. You have 22, 4 of which are not needed. A terminating semicolon is not needed although won't hurt.

Comment: I understand that fields with similar names hold same type of info. However, this is still considered a non-normalized structure. It is a balancing act between normalization and ease of data entry/output. "Normalize until it hurts, denormalize until it works." I have utilized similar structure because it suits my needs. Just make sure it is best for your situation in the long run.

Comment: I will keep that limit in mind for the future, this _shouldn't_ be changing as it is the core collection of tables in the database that hold our part info but I'm sure I'll be eating my words here in bit. Anyway, the advice is very appreciated!

Comment: I ended up having to use UNION queries to perform some graphing of non-normalized fields but I am still satisfied structure was best for our situation. Now your question has code that does not coincide with the original narrative. As now presented, I can see nothing wrong with the SQL. I do prefer CurrentDb.Execute over DoCmd.RunSQL.

Comment: @June7 I figured out the issue here, when I made this PartCreationLog table I was going much too quickly and didn't follow my naming conventions for the field names. I had thought they were captioned as I have done everywhere else in the system, but as soon as the names were changed to the correct convention it pasted in exactly as expected.